# Chart js 2.x renders the canvas invisible

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using `chartjs` version 2 it works very good in all the browsers except chrome and it renders the charts invisible .When i change the size of page by chrome ,it shows the charts . Anyone can give me a hint to fix this problem ?

chrome version : 51

Comment: Is the `<chart>` element visible (you've not set `display: none` or anything) before you create the chart on the canvas?

Comment: Thank you so much , the problem was exactly this . I sat the main container's display to none and when i had all the responses from jquery ajax , again i sat it to block .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas element that the chart is being rendered to must be visible. Make sure you've not set `display: none` to the canvas before rendering the chart.